# building a .net standard library with dotnet with third party package

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I create a .net standard 2.0 library

I add a reference to log4net

I run the following:

```
dotnet publish --output d:\temp\publishout
```

My question is why am I seeing all this output in the publish folder?

I would expect something like e.g. System.Linq to be part of the full .net framework and .net core 2.0 runtime which would already be installed on the machine

```
    Directory: D:\temp\publishout


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       13/01/2018     20:32                runtimes
-a----       13/01/2018     20:32          56477 ClassLibraryStandard.deps.json
-a----       13/01/2018     20:32           4096 ClassLibraryStandard.dll
-a----       13/01/2018     20:32            244 ClassLibraryStandard.pdb
-a----       08/03/2017     19:26         221184 log4net.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:13          21856 System.AppContext.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:13          93432 System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58         180984 System.Collections.Immutable.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          88472 System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:13          34224 System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:13          27544 System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:13          22432 System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14         127304 System.Linq.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14          32504 System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58         428784 System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          29608 System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14          71392 System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          31168 System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          29632 System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14          57720 System.Security.Claims.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          23472 System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14          45504 System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          21736 System.Security.Principal.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14         114080 System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:15          50016 System.Threading.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58          24328 System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14          22400 System.Threading.Thread.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:14          22416 System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
-a----       11/06/2016     23:15         606432 System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
-a----       21/12/2017     17:58         138104 System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
```

Comment: .NET Standard library has no need to be published. When it is referenced by a .NET Framework 4.7.1 app, you can check what are the dependencies required (which should be less).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because before .NET Standard 2.0, some implementations were shipped as assemblies in the individual packages, and build output for .NET Core excluded it since those packages were part of the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` metapackage.

For .NET Standard 2.0, a lot of packages are no longer used and `NETStandard.Library` version 2.0.0 includes all the reference assemblies needed for compilation.

The problem here is that some packages were built "for .NET Standard 1.*" but are now "in .NET Standard 2.0".

For example, NETStandard 1.6 applications had to add `System.Data.Common` manually to use the contained types. `NETStandard.Library` version 2.0.0 already contains the types and there is no need for this package.

When you publish a .NET Core 2.0 app, a trimming logic detects this package and removes it. This does not happen for .NET standard projects as there is no trimming logic applied here, hence you end up with DLLs in your publish output. It is to see if this is a missing optimisation or as designed ([opened a GitHub issue for it](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1855)).

However, as @Lex Li already mentioned in the comments, you hardly ever need the publish output of a .NET Standard library. Use project references or share the project via NuGet packages instead. The publish output would only be needed for a plugin-based architecture for which the workaround would currently be to make the plugin target the same framework as the application (e.g. create a .NET Core library instead of .NET Standard).